# Python - Pandas - Count the number of character occurrence in a string and replace the string value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**EDITED :**

I have the following dataframe

```
Name        Code    
Cedric      AMMMM           
Joe         A       
Mickael     AMMCX           
Dupond      MMMMMMM

Jean        AMMMCMC
```

I want to count the number of character occurrence of values for the **Code** columns. And replace the value by the concatenation of the character and the number of occurence.

My expected result is the following :

```
Name        Code    
Cedric      1A4M            
Joe         1A      
Mickael     1A2M1C1X            
Dupond      7M

Jean        1A3M1C1M1C
```

I have tried with the following method :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in "".join(set(row.Code)):
        num = test.count(i)
        df.loc[index,"Code"] = val + str(num) + i
```

But in reality i have a huge dataframe of more than 800 000 rows. And when i execute this code, the process is too long.

I'm searching a better solution to do that.

**Edited:** I added a last example to my dataframes. Previous responses doesn't handle this example. And i want to handle this use case

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my opinion is better create new question like edited old one, because now answers not match your changed question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all,

Here are a comparison of two methods:

```
from itertools import groupby

%timeit df['Code'] = [''.join(f"{len(''.join(group))}{key}" for key, group in groupby(x)) for x in df['Code']]

CPU times: user 511 µs, sys: 7 µs, total: 518 µs
Wall time: 524 µs
```

and

```
def encode(code):
    cpt=1 
    n=len(code)
    res=''
    for i in range(n):
        if i == n-1 or code[i] != code[i+1]:
            res += str(cpt)+code[i]
            cpt=1
        else: cpt+=1
    return res

%timeit result['CDSCENARIO']=result.CDSCENARIO.apply(encode)

CPU times: user 855 µs, sys: 10 µs, total: 865 µs
Wall time: 871 µs
```

First method is faster than second.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension with `f-string` working for `python 3.6+` and also add `sorted` by index for not change ordering:

```
df['Code'] = [''.join(f'{x.count(i)}{i}' for i in sorted(set(x),key=x.index)) for x in df['Code']]
```

Or use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

df['Code'] = [''.join(f'{j}{i}' for i, j in Counter(x).items()) for x in df['Code']]


print (df)
      Name      Code
0   Cedric      1A4M
1      Joe        1A
2  Mickael  1A2M1C1X
3   Dupond        7M
```

**Performance**:

```
#[40000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [119]: %timeit df['Code'] = [''.join(f'{j}{i}' for i, j in Counter(x).items()) for x in df['Code']]
276 ms ± 9.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [120]: %timeit df['Code'] = [''.join(f'{x.count(i)}{i}' for i in sorted(set(x),key=x.index)) for x in df['Code']]
262 ms ± 3.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#U9-Forward solution
In [124]: %timeit df['Code']=df['Code'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([''.join(map(str,i)) for i in Counter(x).items()]))
339 ms ± 51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `collections.Counter` in an `apply` parameter, and also use a double `''.join` for making a string from a `dict`ionary:

```
from collections import Counter
df['Code']=df['Code'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([''.join(map(str,i)) for i in Counter(x).items()]))
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
      Name      Code
0   Cedric      A1M4
1      Joe        A1
2  Mickael  A1M2C1X1
3   Dupond        M7
```

Answer (score 1):

Counting must care about non consecutives duplicates.

first a function which encode a code :

```
def encode(code):
    cpt=1 
    n=len(code)
    res=''
    for i in range(n):
        if i == n-1 or code[i] != code[i+1]:
            res += str(cpt)+code[i]
            cpt=1
        else: cpt+=1
    return res
```

Example: `scan('AABBCA')` -> `'2A2B1C1A'`.

Then just apply : `df['Code']=df.Code.apply(encode)`, for :

```
      Name       Code
0   Cedric       1A4M
1      Joe         1A
2  Mickael   1A2M1C1X
3   Dupond         7M
4     Jean 1A3M1C1M1C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter from collections` in order to count the occurrences. Later you can `join` the key and value pairs. Over that you can apply `df.apply` function of a pandas DataFrame

```
from collections import Counter as ctr
df['Code'] = df['Code'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([''.join(map(str, val[::-1])) for val in ctr(x).items()]))
```

Here i am using `val[::-1]`, so that output will get at par with your expectations.

```
    Name      Code  
0   Cedric    1A4M
1   Joe       1A    
2   Mickael   1A1X1C2M  
3   Dupond    7M
```